# Bootstrap Table Row Selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

[image: Example]

I can't seem to get the entire row highlighted. Whatever row is the one with the sorted_1 class on it doesn't take the selected highlight when I mark it active. Even when manually setting the background on the cell when it is sorted doesn't produce a result. Any thoughts?

[image: My Code Here]

```
             <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="accountTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width: 50%;">Account Name
                        </th>
                        <th style="width: 50%;">Profit Center Number
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Test Acct</td>
                        <td>XXXX99753</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Test Acct 2</td>
                        <td>XXXX99885</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Account 3</td>
                        <td>XXXX99885</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Z Account</td>
                        <td>XXXX99885</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Also, of course, calling this at the end of my script section.

```
$('#accountTable').dataTable();
```

Comment: can You show us the html and css?

Comment: Added the HTML, there is no CSS. I'm just adding the class 'active' with JS which exists in bootstrap.

Comment: You're talking about DataTables highlighting the row when the "active" class is added right?  Generally, just <tr class="active"> is enough to tell DataTables what to do if I recall right

Comment: check out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/28175/  , is it what You intend to do? seems to be working fine

Comment: If so, the problem is most likely beyond the provided code, or (unlikely) the reset() ? function

Comment: @SebastianKrysiak you missed the part where I said it is specifically happening to the cell that is being sorted. You aren't using a cell that does sorting in your fiddle.

Comment: @Ryan if You click in th the table gets sorted and active class is not lost, try it out. (the fiddle is missing the sorting icons but sorting itself works)

Comment: @SebastianKrysiak Apologies, I see it now. Still not working in my situation, but what I discovered is that I'm using an internal stylesheet that is basically conflicting with everything that the active class tries to do. I removed it and then it somehow broke hover so that the same issue I was having with selected rows was then happening to rows hovered over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
table.dataTable td.sorting_1,
table.dataTable td.sorting_2,
table.dataTable td.sorting_3,
table.dataTable th.sorting_1,
table.dataTable th.sorting_2,
table.dataTable th.sorting_3 {
    background: none !important;
}
```

Seems that this was the issue. I'm using an internal stylesheet that is stock on these projects and it had this lovely section :/

Answer (score 0):

Add style definition for `td`:

```
.active td {
  background: red !important;
}
```

also you can add this style

```
tr:not(.active):hover td {
  background: #e99 !important;
}
```

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6xjwjwjq/2/)**

Comment: Yeah, not working unfortunately. I think it's related to how the sorting works in bootstrap tables.

Comment: Nothing interesting. It actually just clears out the hidden fields that hold the values from the cells.

Comment: Not on my end, see the answer I posted.